# How can I insert the numbers of the 3D matrix into 2D matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, matrix

Suppose that A is a three-dimensional matrix like the following:

```
A = [np.zeros((3, 8)) for _ in range(20)]
```

and B is a two-dimensional matrix that has 60 rows and 8 columns containing numbers. What should I do if I want to put numbers from matrix B into matrix A and use a loop to write code?

```
A[0][0] = B[0] 
A[0][1] = B[1] 
A[0][2] = B[2] 
A[1][0] = B[3]
A[1][1] = B[4]
A[1][2] = B[5]
...
A[20][0] = B[58]
A[20][1] = B[59]
A[20][2] = B[60]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question right. You can use `.flat` + indexing:

```py
A = [np.zeros((3, 8)) for _ in range(20)]
B = np.arange(60 * 8).reshape(60, 8)

for i, subl in enumerate(A):
    subl.flat[:] = B.flat[i * 3 * 8 :]

print(*A, sep="\n\n")
```

Prints:

```py
[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15.]
 [16. 17. 18. 19. 20. 21. 22. 23.]]

[[24. 25. 26. 27. 28. 29. 30. 31.]
 [32. 33. 34. 35. 36. 37. 38. 39.]
 [40. 41. 42. 43. 44. 45. 46. 47.]]

...
```